# connectedAndroidTest and release build type

Tags: android, gradle, instrumentation

I'm using gradle:1.2.3

I would like to run my androidConntectTests (instrumentation tests) on release (signed, minified) configuration, but I cannot.

My build types:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {         
        minifyEnabled false
        debuggable true
    }

    robotium {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        debuggable false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

I have read, that those tests can only be run on debbugable configurations, so I made "robotium" build type (see above), but it still does not work.

When I try calling "gradle tasks" it shows only connectedAndroidTest-Flavour-Debug, and calling "connectedAndroidTest-Flavour-Release/Robobium" simply fails with "task XXX not found in root project".

Is there any way to make instrumentation tests run on diffrent build type?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The android gradle plugin will create test variants for all your flavors. To switch the build type used you can do this, as stated [in the documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Basics-and-Configuration)

> Currently only one Build Type is tested. By default it is the debug Build Type, but this can be reconfigured with:

```
android {
    ...
    testBuildType "staging"
}
```